# Making interacting gears in 2D

Tags: 2d, rotation, godot, rigidbody

I want to create mutually rotating gears for a puzzle game.

I looked at a lot of material, but didn't understand how to make a RigidBody2D stay in one place correctly and interact with each other.

Here is the code I use:

```
extends RigidBody2D
var angle = 1
signal clicked
var held = false
var c 
var vec 
var speed:float = 100
var angele:float = 100
func _input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        if event.pressed:
            c=true
            emit_signal("clicked", self)
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        if !event.pressed:
            c=false


func _physics_process(delta:float)->void:
    global_transform.get_rotation()
    global_transform.interpolate_with(transform.rotated(rotation), 10)
    if c == true and held:
        global_transform.origin = get_global_mouse_position()
        vec = Vector2(get_position())
    if c == false and vec != null:
        position = vec
    #rotation = deg2rad(angle)
    


func _integrate_forces(state):
    #global_transform.get_rotation()
    #global_transform.interpolate_with(transform.rotated(rotation), 10)
    transform = transform.interpolate_with(transform.rotated(rotation), rotation)
    #contact_monitor = true
    #print(transform.rotated(rotation))
    
func pickup():
    if held:
        return
    mode = RigidBody2D.MODE_STATIC
    held = true
    
func drop(impulse=Vector2.ZERO):
    if held:
        mode = RigidBody2D.MODE_RIGID
        held = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to make a RigidBody2D stay in one place

From a design approach, you would make an `StaticBody2D` (or some other body) and a `PinJoint2D` with your `RigidBody2D`.

From a programmer approach, you would write `state.transform` in `_integrate_forces` (which is also the most common way to do a teleport). *For reference, the `state` parameter you get in `_integrate_forces` is of type [`Physics2DDirectBodyState`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physics2ddirectbodystate.html).*

And if you rather use a lower level API, you can write the transform of the `RigidBody2D` at any time with `Physics2DServer.body_set_state`, which will be understood as a teleport (Godot will not solve the collision as if the `RigidBody2D` moved from the prior transform to the new one). For example:

```
Physics2DServer.body_set_state(
    get_rid(),
    Physics2DServer.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
    Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(new_position)
)
```

And neither of the approaches described above would require changing the `mode` of the `RigidBody2D`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about the current tool like PinJoint2D then it changes everything and the understanding becomes clearer. I will try following your advice.